# Prevent Back Button or Display Error After Record Has Been Deleted in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC application.

How do I display an error message instead of returning the view if the user clicks the back button in the browser?

For example, I have a function where the user can delete a log. After deletion the controller method redirects them to a page. Thats all fine.

But if the user clicks the back button after they've been redirected, they are returned back to the same page which shows the now deleted record. So how do I validate to check the record still exists each time when the back button is clicked?

My code to close a log is:

```
 public ActionResult CloseLog(int id)
 {
        var query = from log in db.Logs where log.LogID == id select log;
        foreach (Log log in query)
        {
          log.DateTimeResolved = System.DateTime.Now;
          Response response = new Response
          {
              ResponseText = "This log is now closed. Please call the Service Desk on XXXX if needed.",
              UserName = User.Identity.Name,
              DateTimeOfUpdate = System.DateTime.Now,
              LogID = log.LogID
          };
          db.Responses.Add(response);
        }
       db.SaveChanges();
       return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); 
    }
```

And my code to view

```
 public ActionResult CreateServiceRequestResponse(int? id)
    {
        if (id.HasValue)
        {
            LogID = id.Value;
        }
        var Responses = (from a in db.Responses where a.LogID == LogID select new ResponseViewModel { ResponseText = a.ResponseText, DateTimeOfUpdate = a.DateTimeOfUpdate, Username = a.UserName });
        var ServiceRequest = (from a in db.ServiceRequests where a.LogID == LogID select new ServiceRequestViewModel { RequestType = a.RequestType, AdditionalInformation = a.AdditionalInformation, EstimatedResolveDate = a.EstimatedResolveDate, LogID = a.LogID});
        ViewBag.ServiceRequestData = ServiceRequest;
        ViewBag.Data = Responses;
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this on the place where you think you should do validation.

```
var query = from log in db.Logs where log.LogID == id select log;
if (!query.Any())
{
    // Or you can have your own handler.
    throw new HttpException(404, "Page not found");
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. My query is:  var query = (from logs in db.Logs where logs.LogID == LogID && logs.DateTimeResolved != null select new LogViewModel { LogID = logs.LogID });

Comment: And i've placed your code underneath it and i get this excpetion regardless if log is resolved or not